# How do I read a tab-delimited file into a List array?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am firing up Visual C# (2010 Express) for the first time, and I've created a new project for a WindowsFormsApplication.  No code has been written yet, but I created a button and placed it on Form1.  Then, I double-clicked the button and am taken to the part of the code where you write what happens when the button is push/clicked.

The first thing I would like to do is read data from a LARGE tab-delimited text file (30MB).  The text file contains 7 structured columns of data like names, age, favorite color, animal, etc.  Nothing tricky or fancy in the text formatting.  I'm using the code below:

```
File.ReadLines(sourceFilePath)
.Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
.ToArray();
```

But my more basic question is how do I establish and define File and sourceFilePath?  With the code above I get "The name 'File' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Add `using System.IO;` to your form class to get access to the File class.

Comment: ReadAllLines will create an array of stirngs, delimited by NewLine (\r\n). Do you want to split it by tab as well, or only by tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following line to the top of your C# file:

```
using System.IO;
```

This will allow the use of the File class, which is in the System.IO namespace.

As for defining sourceFilePath, that's just a variable, which you can declare and set to whatever file path you need, e.g.

```
string sourceFilePath = @"c:\data\file.csv";
```

Note the use of @ before the string literal; this prevents the backslashes from being treated as the start of escape sequences. You can instead just escape the bakslashes, e.g.

```
string sourceFilePath = "c:\\data\\file.csv";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split by tab key then you can try using ReadAllText method, and then a Split method, where you define delimiter (by tab):

```
 string[] delimitedByTab = File.ReadAllText(@"file").Split('\t').ToArray();
```

And use System.IO; namespace for File class

Answer (score 0):

The File class resides the System.IO namespace. You leverage it in your application with the following:

```
using System.IO;
```

As for defining the contents of sourceFilePath, you are going to need either to hard-code the value to a fixed location, which is not always advisable, or devise a mechanism for the user to specify that path, possibly through one of the various CommonDialogs that are available. Some research on the CommonDialogs should help push you a bit further in developing your project.